# Exact sequence of cohomology $0 \rightarrow H^{n - 1}(X) \rightarrow H^{n - 1}(Y) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

Say I have the following exact sequence of cohomology:
\begin{align*}
0 \rightarrow H^{n - 1}(X) \rightarrow H^{n - 1}(Y) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
Is there anything I can say about the relationship between $H^{n - 1}(X)$ and $H^{n - 1}(Y)$?
Thanks!

Comment: What sort of things are you looking for? For example, clearly $H^{n-1}(X)$ injects into $H^{n-1}(Y)$. If they are finitely generated, you can say more.

Comment: Perhaps if you gave some more context it would help. Where does this sequence originate from?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thank you! Here I'm looking for the $(n-1)$-th cohomology $H^{n - 1}(X \setminus \{x_1, x_2\})$ for an compact connected $n$-manifold $X$ and two points $x_1, x_2$ within $X$. The exact sequence was obtained from Mayer-Vietoris

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you! Above is the description.

Comment: The last surjection there splits, so you can actually write this as a direct sum of a sequence $0 \to H^{n-1}(X) \to H^{n-1}(Y) \to \Bbb Z \to 0$ and $0 \to \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z \to 0$. Since the first sequence again ends in a projective module, we can play the same game to conclude $H^{n-1}(Y) \cong H^{n-1}(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$. The difficulty in resolving extension problems only comes when sequences don't end in projectives.